# Sensor Scratched/Marks

Tags: sensor, equipment-damage, cleaning, maintenance

I need some feedback on what these marks might be.

Iso: 100,
Aperture: f22,
Shutter: 1/8.
Applied "DEHAZE" in Lightroom so that the you can see the lines clearer.
Ignore the sunflare to the left of the picture.

I get this same result on all my lenses, so its not the lenses.  I have not cleaned the sensor yet as I am waiting on a cleaning kit to arrive.
[image: sensor_issue]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to your camera's manual on how to set your cam into sensor cleaning mode. This will open the shutter and flip the mirror up (if there is one). You should now see the exposed sensor. Use a strong flashlight and shine it onto the sensor from the side. You should now see, if there is any damage on the sensor.

For me, this looks like smear on the sensor, but it might also be scratches. If there is just traces of a botched cleaning attempt, you can remove it with the cleaning kit you ordered. If these are scratches, then you are in for a costly repair.

Comment: Hi Kai, thanks for your feedback.  The camera is a Canon 80D, I've performed the cleaning action in the menu before but it doesn't seem to get rid of it.  Additionally I have inspected the sensor and I cant see any scratches whatsoever, just a little bit of dust. So i'm also thinking that this might be a form of residue of a oily nature left over by something, as I cant see any scratches from any angle (used my phones macro lens and flash light to inspect the sensor). (bought the camera second hand).

Comment: @Nico.P I would return the camera. That looks like a reason someone would sell it.

Comment: Don't you just love people who sell stuff they know is damaged/defective without disclosing such to the buyer?